# SQL - selecting userid which has max number of not null rows in a different table

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I've 3 tables say A,B,C.

Table A has `userid` column.
Table B has `caid` column.
Table C has `lisid` and `image` columns.

one `userid` can have one or several `caid`s.
one `caid` can have one or several `lisid`s.

how do I select a `userid` which has maximum number of rows with `image` column as `not null` (in some `lisid`s `image` column is blank and in some it has some value).

can someone please help.

Comment: We can help once you [show us what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: You should also post the structure of your table, how are you associating `userid` with `caid`, and `lisid` with `caid`?

Comment: wew, which is true? `MySQL` or `Oracle`?

Comment: I could only get this far `select a.userid, c.title
    from schema.C c, schema.A a, schema.B b
    where c.image is not null
    and c.caid = b.caid
    and b.userid = a.userid `   .   Its oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, the ids are spread among the tables in a reasonable fashion.  If so, the following should do this:

```
select b.userid, count(*)
from TableB b join
     TableC c
     on b.caid = c.caid
where c.image is not null
group by b.userid
order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```

The question in the comments is how you connect TableA to TableB and TableB to TableC.  The reasonable approach is to have the userid in TableB and the caid in TableC.

Getting all the rows with the max requires a bit more work.  Essentially, you have to join in the above query to get the list

```
select s.*
from (select b.userid, count(*) as cnt
      from TableB b join
           TableC c
           on b.caid = c.caid
     ) s
     (select count(*) as maxcnt
      from TableB b join
           TableC c
           on b.caid = c.caid
      group by b.userid
      order by count(*) desc
      limit 1
     ) smax
     on s.cnt = smax.cnt
```

Other databses have a set of functions called window functions/ranking functions that make this sort of query much simpler.  Alas, MySQL does not offer these.

Comment: how about user's that have the same value of `count(*)` which is also the maximum value.?

Comment: @JohnWoo . . . Before the question was edited, I believe it said "a maximum number".

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  this gave me results.Thanks a lot. how do I modify above to get all caid's  per `userid` that have max rows with `image` column `not null`. I tried to include `caid` in `group by` but didnt work. I tried selecting `unique userid` in select statement and then group by `userid` and `caid` , didnt work. any suggestions